# Meaning of "this <noun> breaks it"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I am currently involved in open source project. Somebody wrote:

> This commit breaks it.

What does this mean? I think that it means either:

1. This commit created the issue, or
2. This commit fixed the issue.

Source: https://github.com/dreamstalker/rehlds/issues/332

Comment: [To break](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/break) has a lot of different meanings, but they all mean something bad. So it's 1.

Comment: @Glorfindel "to break" does not ALWAYS mean something bad. If we say "his fever broke" that means his fever ended, which presumably is good. There's also "I got a break", which means, "something good happened to me". But in this case "break" is something bad

Comment: In the first case, *fever* is bad, so if it breaks, it's good. In the second case, *break* is a noun.

Comment: Note that ***it*** doesn't represent the *issue, error, fault* - it refers to the *project* (which was "broken, made inoperative" by committing those faulty code changes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imagine you're probably aware of what a "commit" is, but, for anyone that isn't, it's a name for a record of changes in a [version control system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) (a system which tracks changes to documents – that is, keeps a record of the *versions* of the documents). Each commit contains a set of changes introduced by the current version as compared to the previous version.

The context (provided by the link in the OP) is that someone has reported an error with a program. A person involved with the maintenance and development of the program has then responded:

> This commit breaks it.

Provided in the response is a reference to a specific commit (set of changes).

---

The correct interpretation is #1 in your question – that this commit introduced (or created) the issue. Please refer to this definition (from Oxford Dictionaries):

> [**break**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/break)
>   VERB
>
> **1.3** Make or become inoperative:
>   *[no object] "the machine has broken and they can't fix it until next week"*
>   *[with object] "he's broken the video"*

In this sentence, "it" refers to the program that is broken (as a result of the commit).

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, it was the commit bit that I needed to check up on, but then I saw it was GitHub and it all made sense!

To clarify, a *commit* is a submission of code. The commenter is basically stating that this new piece of code causes an error with the program (believe it's the game, Half Life.

The first phrase is the most suitable explanation:

> This commit created the issue